# protect my blog content

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Good evening,

is there any way to protect my blog content (text-picture) from copy/paste.

I've tried Javascript, but it's easy to desactivate it.

Any magical way to protect my post? another way without JS maybe ?

Thanks

Comment: [Berne Convention](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berne_Convention_for_the_Protection_of_Literary_and_Artistic_Works)

Comment: Use a .GIF file for each individual letter :) That'd make it considerably more annoying to copy..

Comment: a .GIF for each lettre , funny :) i'm curious, how to make this? i have a constraint of weight, i think it will make the blog weightly , but i'm still curious :)

Comment: Yea you'd probably need some program to convert your text to a series of IMG tags.  Sure, the HTML would be like 10 times the size but at least you can give your blog that much desired "ransom note" appearance.

Answer (score 5):

NO. THERE IS NO WAY. If you don't want people copying things, don't put them on the internet.

Any HTML debugging tool would allow anyone to grab whatever they want.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, no real way to protect or block contents.
But some tricks to make more difficult to drag/select text or images.

some tricks in CSS, to "block" selection:

```
    * {
        -webkit-user-select: none;
        -khtml-user-select: none;
        -moz-user-select: -moz-none;
        -o-user-select: none;
        user-select: none;
    }
```

some trick in HTML to stop drag images:

```
<body ondragstart="return false;" ondrop="return false;">
```

to prevent printing on paper your content using CSS:

```
@media print { * {display: none !important;} }
```

All this are trick that can be breaked if user have some knowledge on CSS, HTML.

Answer (score 0):

In a word: No.  Javascript's one way, and that's easily disabled.  Another way is to place a div over your content so people can't copy&paste, but they can still just grab the pure HTML.